# jquery callback for all hrefs in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div:

```
<div id="left-nav">
    <a href="#" class="current">
        <span class="icon dashboard"></span>
        Dashboard
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon users"></span>
        Users
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon venues"></span>
        Venues
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon payments"></span>
        Payments
    </a>
</div>
```

I can specify an event handler for each `a` one by one, but is there a way I can ask for a call back for all of them once? So I just say, trigger this function when ANY `a` tags are clicked? Rather than looping through each and assigning a call back.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us what you have done till yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#left-nav").on( "click", "a", function(){
    alert("clicked!");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: 'this' here is left-nav, any way to get <a> element that was clicked?

Comment: '$(this)' will be <a> element, not the div.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="left-nav">
    <a href="#" class="current">
        <span class="icon dashboard"></span>
        Dashboard
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon users"></span>
        Users
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon venues"></span>
        Venues
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon payments"></span>
        Payments
    </a>
</div>
```

Add jquery

```
$('#left-nav a').click(function()
{
    //your element 
    alert(this.id);//for element which have been clicked
});
```

Comment: 'this' here is left-nav, any way to get <a> element that was clicked?

Comment: No this.id will return you a clicked

Comment: Not true, this.id returns left-nav, not the 'a' that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#left-nav").on( "click", "a", function(){
    alert("clicked!");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain your selector this way:

```
$('#left-nav a').on('click', function(){
    alert(this.className + ' clicked.');
});
```

and if your all the anchor tags are dynamically generated then you can delegate your event to a closest static parent which was available at the time of page load:

```
$('#left-nav').on('click', 'a', function(){
    alert(this.className + ' clicked.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#left-nav").delegate( "click", "a", function(){
    //your code
});
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method"